# Retrivieng data from database using objects.all() not working

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new to django and python and I am trying to retrieve some entries from a a database, but when calling Criminal.objects.all() I don't get anything, hence "Nothing" is displayed. However, I checked and I have 2 entries in my table.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.

class Criminal(models.Model):
    cid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cssn = models.IntegerField()
    cfirst_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    clast_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cdob = models.DateField()
    cpob = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = "criminal"
```

views.py

```
from django.http import *
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *


# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name': 'SE mini project'})

def index(request):
    criminals = Criminal.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'obj': criminals})
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1> {{name}} </h1>

{% if obj %}
    {% for v in obj %}
        {{v.cfirst_name}}<br>
        {{v.clast_name}}<br>
        {{v.cdob}}<br>
        {{v.cpob}}<br>

{% endfor %}
{% else %}
Nothing
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Livia, can you add urls.py ?

Comment: seems your URL is pointing to wrong view

Comment: `from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns= [
    path('', views.home, name='home')
]`

Comment: Indeed there was a problem in the urls.py, after adding     path('index', views.index, name='index') and path('', views.home, name='home') it worked.